# Heroku and application home

Tags: heroku, state

Ive used :

*heroku create*

To create a heroku application, and succesfully pushed/pulled it into /output a separate github repo.

But I'm wondering :

Where does heroku store the name of my application?  In an empty directory, does not result in any new files.

Does heroku thus rely 100% entirely on git to manage the entire state of the application? Or is there some local information for security/etc that is stored on a local machine.

**If this is the case, what is the "purpose" of the heroku create command - Does it simply create a new url and register it with the heroku cloud ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you run `heroku create` it creates the application on Heroku and then adds the heroku git remote in your git repo. `git remote -v` locally will show this.

When you then use the heroku CLI it extracts the name of the application from the `heroku` remote that `heroku create` added for you.

If you choose not to use `heroku` as your remote name, I myself prefer `production` and `staging` then you will need to use the `--app` parameter to heroku commands to identify the application which you wish to interface to.

UPDATE: If you look from line 21 of https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/base.rb you can see how it works.

Comment: thanks maybe fix some typos though ?> Some of the finer points are hard to understand .